# I use class_copyIvarList to get ivar list, but why property can't be found if overwrite get function

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

```
unsigned int count = 0;
Ivar *ivarList = class_copyIvarList([self.person class], &count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    Ivar ivar = ivarList[i];
    const char * name = ivar_getName(ivar);
    NSLog(@"%s", name);
}
```

**self.person** has a readonly property name, I overwrite name's get

```
- (NSString *)name {
   return @"";
}
```

Then, I can't find it by **class_copyIvarList**.

I can't understand this.

Answer (score 0):

You're giving the definition of the setter method and you haven't created the ivar in the `Person` class. Thus there is no `name` ivar in the class.

Either create an `ivar` like

```
@implementation Person
@synthesize name = _name;
- (NSString *)name {
  return @"";
}
```

Or inspect `class_copyIvarList` class property instead of instance variables (ivars)

```
unsigned int count = 0;
objc_property_t *propertyList = class_copyPropertyList([self.person class], &count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  objc_property_t property = propertyList[i];
  const char * propertyName = property_getName(property);
  NSLog(@"%s", propertyName);
}
```